# How can I create a flexible JSON structure in Node Red?

Tags: json, csv, object, node-red

Assume I have the following CSV:

```
A_Key;B_Key;C_Key;...;X_Key
Value 1;2;Value 1.3;...;Value 1.24
Value 1;;Value 2.3;...;Value 2.24
...
```

I have already created a Node Red Template that allows me to extract some of the key-value-pairs to create a simple JSON output. However, this is a one to one relationship, but what I need is a more flexible solution. There are certain requirements for the Objects that should make the output:

1. All rows have one column that serves as a primary key - let's assume that's the "C Key" column.This primary key must be in the resulting Object.  A second column, "A Key", in our example, contains the type of the object. It is constant and thus ignored.
2. Of the remaining columns, there's a certain list that are mandatory for the upload, but some of the fields may be empty (in this case NULL should be the value). These fields are listed in a sub-object called "Properties"
3. It may happen that a complete column is missing in the CSV. If this is a mandatory column, all objects should still have the key albeit with a NULL value.
4. It may happen that the CSV has additional columns that are not in the mandatory list. These optional attributes should appear in a "catch-all" sub-object called "Extras".

A resulting Object from the CSV above could look like this:

```
[
    {
        "A_Key": "Value 1",
        "C_Key": "Value 1.3",
        "Properties": {
            "B_Key": "2",
            "F_Key": ...,
            ...
            "X_Key": "Value 1.24"
        },
        "Extras": {
           "D_Key": ...,
           "E_Key": ...,
           ...
        }
    },
    {
        "A_Key": "Value 1",
        "C_Key": "Value 2.3",
        "Properties": {
            "B_Key": "NULL",
            "F_Key": ...,
            ...
            "X_Key": "Value 2.24"
        },
        "Extras": {
           "D_Key": ...,
           ...
        }
    },
]
```

I'd like to do the following: I'd like to build a function node "Prepare JSON" in Node Red that iterates over the CSV's columns and uses the column headers as keys for the resulting JSON. I have already prepared a function at the beginning of the flow that sets the required variables:

```
var primaryKey = "C_Key";
var mandatoryPart = "Properties";
var mandatoryKeys = ["B_Key",
"F_Key",
...
"X_Key"];
var optionalPart = "Extras";
var appendOptionalPart = true;

msg.primaryKey = primaryKey;
msg.mandatoryPart = mandatoryPart
msg.mandatoryKeys = mandatoryKeys;
msg.optionalPart = optionalPart;
msg.appendOptionalPart = appendOptionalPart;
```

And I have tried several approaches to get the "Prepare JSON" function running:

```
msg.payload = {
    "A_Key": "Value 1",
    "C_Key": msg.payload.C_Key,
    "Properties": {
        "B_Key": msg.payload.B_Key
    },
    optionalPart: msg.optionalPart
}

//for(var i =0; i<msg.mandatoryParts.length;i++)
//{  
//  msg.payload.Properties.push(msg.payload[msg.mandatoryKeys[i]].value);
//    msg.payload.Properties.push(msg.mandatoryKeys[i]);
//}
return msg;
```

The static part at the top works fine, however, how can I set the name of an element's key dynamically? Have a look at the line "optionalPart": the variable is "msg.optionalPart" but when I try to access it directly Node Red complains about the dot. I tried enclosing it in escaped quotes but Node Red doesn't like the backslash character at the beginning of the line either. I also tried string concatanation and, of course, if I put the variable name in quotes it's printed verbatim in the output...

The commented part in the bottom was my first attempt at looping over the elements, I'm stuck here, too. Any help is greately appreciated!

Here's an image of what the flow currently looks like:

[image: Current configuration of the flow]

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with JSONata, which is a language that eases the transformation of data.

The main part of your Node-RED flow will be a change node with this JSONata expression:

```
payload.{"A_Key" :A_Key, "C_Key" :C_Key, "Properties" : {"B_Key" :B_Key, "F_Key" :F_Key, "X_Key" :X_Key}, "Extras" : {"D_Key" :D_Key, "E_Key" :E_Key }}
```

This is the flow to import for your Node-RED, just fix the file name path:

```
[{"id":"52781b93.a86794","type":"tab","label":"Flow 3","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"fc475896.7f6a68","type":"csv","z":"52781b93.a86794","name":"","sep":",","hdrin":true,"hdrout":"","multi":"mult","ret":"\\n","temp":"","skip":"0","x":430,"y":260,"wires":[["c6f562e7.6189c"]]},{"id":"282d5fcd.692cb","type":"debug","z":"52781b93.a86794","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":770,"y":260,"wires":[]},{"id":"22fa22d.c2868de","type":"inject","z":"52781b93.a86794","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":120,"y":260,"wires":[["93544cf8.57fad"]]},{"id":"93544cf8.57fad","type":"file in","z":"52781b93.a86794","name":"Read CSV","filename":"f1.csv","format":"utf8","chunk":false,"sendError":false,"x":280,"y":260,"wires":[["fc475896.7f6a68"]]},{"id":"c6f562e7.6189c","type":"change","z":"52781b93.a86794","name":"Prepare JSON","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"payload.{\"A_Key\" :A_Key, \"C_Key\" :C_Key, \"Properties\" : {\"B_Key\" :B_Key, \"F_Key\" :F_Key, \"X_Key\" :X_Key}, \"Extras\" : {\"D_Key\" :D_Key, \"E_Key\" :E_Key }}","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":600,"y":260,"wires":[["282d5fcd.692cb"]]}]
```

EDIT: adding a potential answer for your question about dynamic element's key.

If I understood correctly you want to add to `msg.payload` a key that is variable. For that purpose, you can use [Javascript Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

In your function node it would be like this:

```
msg.payload = {
    "A_Key": "Value 1",
    "C_Key": msg.payload.C_Key,
    "Properties": {
        "B_Key": msg.payload.B_Key
    },
    //optionalPart: msg.optionalPart
    [optionalPart]:["Z_Key"]
    // or [msg.optionalPart]:["Z_Key"] if more appropriate for your logic
}
```

You will have the property key "Extras" added to `msg.payload`.

As a side note (as this is not part of your OP), note that this below of your code is unclear and probably troubled if `msg.payload.C_Key` and `msg.payload.B_Key` are not properly initialized.

```
"C_Key": msg.payload.C_Key,
"B_Key": msg.payload.B_Key,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've come this far on my own, yet (althoug i used a Template node): as far as I can see this is fairly static, right? What would happen, e.g., if "E_key", which is optional is "NULL" for one or more objects? In this case I'd like the line to disappear completely, rather than having

    "E_Key": ""

in the "Extras" section - understand what I mean? Also, I'd like to name the fields from the header of the CSV file, i.e. a column called "E_Key" should result as "E_Key" in JSON, OTOH, if the CSV has a column called "foo", I'd like "foo" to be the key automatically.

Comment: I did not capture from the OP the requirement of dynamic header names, so yes, the proposed flow will not fit your need as it is static in that regard (otherwise you would need to change the header name whenever you have a different CSV file). Do you agree that you will need to hardcode a kind of "dictionary" in your code to explicitly tell the header names that are primary and mandatory,? Looks like you were already doing this in your trial code by using statements like: var mandatoryKeys = ["B_Key","F_Key"], right?